# Optimize database for top-k range query

Tags: architecture, distributed-system, system-design, distributed-database

Given the database table below:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    orderId UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    beginTime TIMESTAMP,
    finishTime TIMESTAMP,
    orderBlob BLOB
);
```

How do I shard my database given the SELECT query below. It's basically a top-k range query. See below:

```
select * from orders AS o
where o.beginTime >= startTime and o.finishTime <= endTime
order by (c.finishTime - c.beginTime) DESC
LIMIT K
```

Talking points:

1. Since this is a range query, is it okay to define a clustered index on `beginTime`  given that this will pre-sort the table rows? By the way, this is a write-heavy application, roughly 10 million writes/day. could it impact write speed?
2. Conversely, is it efficient to include a `duration` column(beginTime - endTime) in the `orders` table and define an index on it? My thought is that, with this approach, one could update the `ORDER BY` clause to `order by duration`. In this case I could shard through consistent hash on the `orderId`

Comment: What exact database (it can have a significant impact on what can be done)? Possibly you should consider switching to some analytics engine and replicate data there.